# diw (delete inner word) in bash doesn't work

Tags: key-bindings

I'm running bash as shell, and, after runnning `set -o vi` I would like to delete innner words to the cursor using `diw`, but when I run `diw` nothing happens.

Im on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Vi didn't have text-objects to begin with so there's no reason whatsoever to expect readline's vi mode, a partial re-implementation of vi, to have text-objects. Use Vim itself if you want Vim.

Comment: ... but zsh does! (since version 5.0.8)

Comment: @romainl I expected `diw` works since `dw` works.. What do you mean with "Use Vim itself if you want Vim"?

Comment: `w` is a motion, not a text-object like `iw`. I mean "vi mode is pointless, use the default emacs-like mode and start vim when you need vim".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question about Vim, but about bash.

Answer (score 7):

Readline's vi mode supports motions, but it does not support text objects.

It's possible to hack in support for `diw` and similar commands via your `.inputrc` using something like (untested, stolen from [minos.org's bash settings](https://github.com/minos-org/bash-minos-settings/blob/master/etc%23%23inputrc)):

```
$if mode=vi
set keymap vi-command
"diw": "lbdw"
$endif
```

Note that in bash, you can edit your current commandline in your $EDITOR by pressing `v` whilst in Readline vi mode's command mode, enabling you to harness the full power of Vim for editing your shell commands. (Whilst in the default emacs-style mode, you can do the same via the key combination `<ctrl-x><ctrl-e>`.)